# Windows 7 update failed (language pack update)

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-update

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate and tried to install the language pack for chinese simplified from Windows Update and failed for many times. The error code was `8007065B: Windows Update encountered an unknown error.` What does the code means? I have tried to google it but cannot find anything. What should I do to solve this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem installing Vietnamese

Answer (score 1):

Update: Oops, just noticed this KB does not say it applies to Windows-7.
Leaving the reference around for someone to find related help if possible.

Further: Here is a general [Microsoft Support FixIt link](http://support.microsoft.com/fixit).

---

You could try [**KB971058**: How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058)